# new window or tab is opened now, How can i check it

Tags: javascript, html

How can i check that the new window or tab is opened or exited now of same site ,so i can store/destroy some values in session variable accordingly.
If its possible in php then best then better.
I am using mostly IE 6.0 and above.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Dude they are going to fire up IE6 soon.. Updgrade your browser or switch...

Comment: there should be a virus that checks if its IE6 or 7 and update it. what a wonderful virus that would be

Comment: @J J : You need to upgrade your code to W2 or even W3 standards.. both these has cool features that would keep your visitors intact...

Comment: Actually our site is working from last 11 years in IE. but now we are going to upgrade it. I expecting some solutions.

Comment: What do you mean by "If its possible in php"? PHP is server side and this stuff is client side and can only be done using JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously i haven't tried this in IE but it should be a standard

when you [open a window](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) in your script, you can still control it.

```
var win = window.open("http://example.com");

if (win) {
  // the window is open.

  // you can close it with the close method
  win.close();
}
```

Comment: @lbu: You are saying correct and your code is also correct, i voted it but in my session variable for new window its store new values and for old window its store previous old values even if the new window is not closed or a user can also run old window without closing new window and behaves like without opening a new window.

Comment: did really undertand what you are trying to say, but from the new window, you can access the parent by using `window.opener`